# ffmpeg thumbnail not added and filesize increased too much after using -disposition option

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add a thumbnail to a video. So i used `-disposition` option
Here's the full command I used

```
ffmpeg -i <video1> -i thumb.png -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1 -c:v:1 png -disposition:v:1 attached_pic out.mp4
```

This command gives an output which has all the streams (A,V,IMAGE) but the video player didn't show the thumbnail. Now the problem isn't with the player. Because I encoded an example using this command and the thumbnail was shown!

```
ffmpeg -i video -i image.png -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -c:v:1 png -disposition:v:1 attached_pic out.mp4
```

When I ran this

```
ffmpeg -i video -i thumb.png -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 1 -c:v:1 png -disposition:1 attached_pic out.mp4
```

The file size increased drastically!
Input `1MB vs Output 235MB`!
Now what am I doing wrong?  Why the thumbnail was not added and why the size increased so much?
Also the image seems repeating. 
I found  `25fps` when saw the PNG information metadata.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of trial and errors I figured out `MKV` container treat the Image as a video stream. So switching to `MP4` worked fine! 
so here's the working command
`ffmpeg -i .... attached_pic -f mp4 out.mkv`
Sadly I didn't find any documentation that clearly says about this. 
Hope this will help someone else